# How do you format a line of text within a div when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Using jQuery or straight javascript, how do you identify / select / choose a single line of text from a div with contentEditable on and add formatting to that line of text only?**

I currently have a div with contentEditable set to true, which allows the user to edit the content of the div, adding/removing text as they see fit. However, I want the user to also be able to double-click any line of text within the div and mark that line with a different formatting style. *(i.e. enclose the full line of text within spans and then style the span. Note that I can style the span easily. My problem lies with identifying the line of text the user clicked and enclosing it in span tags)*

Note that since the user can add a lot of content, the div itself is scrollable, so any solution should be able to handle the scrolling.

Comment: Is the text wrapped or each line clearly separated (by <br> or similar)?
In the former case, I think it is harder or even impossible.

Comment: As far as my research tells me, when using contentEditable, firefox separates each line with <br>.
I believe IE separates each line with paragraphs.

Comment: Correction: when you add content to a div with contentEditable on, I have no clue how IE separates the lines (no firebug, IE Dev Toolbar not helpful).

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [fieldSelection plugin](http://laboratorium.0xab.cd/jquery/fieldselection/0.2.3-test/test.html) will allow you to get the text selected by the user.

As far as wrapping the selected line with a span, the usual [jQuery $().wrap()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap#elem) method should do the trick.

Comment: It seems as if the fieldSelection plugin only works on text fields and text areas. My display area is a div (with contentEditable on)

Comment: Completely forgot that you're using a div when looking for a solution. 

I think it's worth adding that I've patched a few other jQuery plugins to work in a context that the original author did not intend. This might be an option with the fieldSelect plugin and if you're not finding a solution elsewhere it might be the best bet. If you choose to go that way and want some help let me know.

Comment: Duly noted and thanks. I'm not sure if I'll go that route yet, but if I do and need help, I'll be sure to ask.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox you can use:

```
// This will give the first selection:
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var txt = range.toString();
var spn = document.createNode('span');
spn.innerHTML = txt;
// Here you can apply style to spn
range.surrondContents(spn); // It will surround your selected text
```

Here is the link to get more help:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.surroundContents

For IE you can use:
You can use same process in IE too.. using range and selection..

Hope it solves your problem.